# Как брать значение из словаря по порядку из списка?

Tags: python, словари

```
translation = 'He hate her'
mylist = translation.split(" ")
print(mylist)

words = {'hate':' ненавидить',
         'she': ' она',
         'He': ' он',
         'I':' Я',
         'love': ' любить',
         'loves': ' любит',
         'see': ' видить',
         'hear': ' слышать',
         'live': ' жить',
         'mouse': ' мышь',
         'world': ' мир',
         'you': ' тебя',
         'him': ' его',
         'her': ' ее',
         'me': ' меня'
         }

for k,v in words.items():
    if k in mylist:
        print(v)
```

Питон выдает   - **ненавидить он ее**

C нарушением порядка, когда должно быть - 
**он ненавидить ее**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные в словарях хранятся в произвольном порядке. При каждом обращении к словарю порядок может быть разный. Разворачивайте алгоритм

```
translation = 'He hate her'
mylist = translation.split(" ")
print(mylist)

words = {'hate':' ненавидить',
         'she': ' она',
         'He': ' он',
         'I':' Я',
         'love': ' любить',
         'loves': ' любит',
         'see': ' видить',
         'hear': ' слышать',
         'live': ' жить',
         'mouse': ' мышь',
         'world': ' мир',
         'you': ' тебя',
         'him': ' его',
         'her': ' ее',
         'me': ' меня'
         }

for k in mylist:
    print(words.get(k, '?' * len(k)))
```

или используйте [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: во ведь и так работает
    print(words.get(k, len(k)))